# Variadic Functions With Variadic Type Parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, variadic-functions

I'm not sure if what I'm attempting is allowed by the standard, and may not even make sense to do, so by all means feel free to correct me.

I'm trying to pass a variable number of `std::function` objects to a function which accepts variadic arguments, and also accepts variadic template parameters. The template parameters specify the return types of the functions that are passed in. The signature of the function looks like so:

```
template <typename ... TRets>
void DoStuff(std::function<TRets...()> funcs...)
```

What I'm attempting to do is pass the return values from each of the `funcs` passed in to another function which accepts them in an expanded value form. E.g. `std::make_shared<TType>(funcs()...);`

I'm using g++ 7.1.1 with the `--std=c++17` flag which causes the compiler to seg fault. Obviously it shouldn't seg fault, but is there anything in the standard that says the above code is invalid? Or perhaps, is there a different syntax to accomplish this goal?

For completeness, here is a minimal working (for some definition of working) example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class MyClass {
    public:
        int m_a;
        double m_b;
        MyClass(int a, double b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {};
};


template <typename TReturn, typename ... Args>
std::shared_ptr<TReturn> CallFunctions(std::function<Args...()> funcs...) {
    // Do stuff here
    return std::make_shared<TReturn>(funcs()...);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto x = CallFunctions<MyClass, int, double>(
        [] () { return 5; },
        [] () { return 3.14; }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Edited to show better intent of my original question

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You might want to submit a bug report if the compiler is segfaulting.

Comment: Do you expect every function passed in to `CallFunctions` to take no arguments and return a value?

Comment: Agreed, I'm going to update to the latest version to make sure it is not still affected by this bug. If it is, then I will file a report. Also I have edited the code in the post to better show intent, but @Yakk 's answer was close enough to get me what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class R, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<R> CallFunctions(std::function<Args()>... funcs) {
  return std::make_shared<R>( funcs()... );
}
```

this is C++11.  It is inefficient.

```
template <class R, class... Args>
auto CallFunctions(Args&&... funcs) 
-> decltype(std::make_shared<R>( funcs()... ))
{
  return std::make_shared<R>( funcs()... );
}
```

which removes the needless type erasure and need to explicly pass the return types.

If you really really want to pass the return types:

```
template <class R, class... Args, class...Fs>
auto CallFunctions(Fs&&... funcs) 
-> decltype(std::make_shared<R>( static_cast<Args>(funcs())... ))
{
  return std::make_shared<R>( static_cast<Args>(funcs())... );
}
```

but I advise doing the 2nd solution above.

Comment: This was close enough to get what I needed, please edit the c++17 example to call the functions using the `funcs()...` syntax and I will accept. I edited the original post to more clearly explain my intent. The body of the `CallFunctions` function then becomes `return std::make_shared<TReturn>(funcs()...);`. I will accept this answer when it has been edited accordingly

Comment: @howard I did not think `funcs()...;` is valid C++17; did something change?  Ah, I see, question edited.

Comment: The best I can gather is that this syntax is covered by parameter pack expansion: `pattern ....` as outlined [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: Is `decltype(std::make_shared<R>(` stuff `))` ever not `std::shared_ptr<R>`, which is shorter and clearer?

Comment: Oh, I guess you want to be SFINAE-friendlier. Never mind.

Comment: @asch the original had overload resolution effects; I wanted to be at least as good.

Comment: @Yakk thanks for the updates. Just one question, are you `static_cast`ing to the r-value reference just to force move semantics?

Comment: @howard because that is roughly what convertingmtom`std::function<Args()>` does to the return value of its argument which is then passed to `make_shared`; #3 is like #1 but more efficient, and different overload rules (it checks you can make then`R`, but hard errors if you pass bad lambdas).  I was going to give #3 another check for lambda compatibility, but as I would use #2 myself I decided not to invest more in it.

Comment: @Howard I just convinced myself in C++17 that `static_cast<Args>` instead of `static_cast<Args&&>` is a better emulation of what `std::function` does and relatively cost-free due to prvalue elision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++17 `std::apply` to use `std::invoke` on each element of the parameter pack.  Then you do not need `std::function` anymore, because `std::invoke` can only call callable objects and also you don't have to give explicit template arguments anymore (which is an anti-pattern anyway).  As a bonus you can even retrieve the return values of the called functions.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

template < typename... R, typename... Args >
auto CallFunctions(Args... funcs) {
    // Do stuff here
  return std::apply(
    [] (auto&&... x) {
      return std::make_tuple(std::make_shared<R>(std::invoke(x))...);
    }, std::make_tuple(funcs...)
    );
}

int main() {
    auto r = CallFunctions<int,double>(
        [] () { return 5; },
        [] () { return 3.14; }
    );

    std::cout << *std::get<0>(r) << ' ' << *std::get<1>(r) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WGXrvOxVufCFR5Qh)</kbd>